# Simple Bus Network simulation

Tags: c++, simulation

[image]

I am simulating a simple bus network (as shown in the picture) using event simulation. There are two buses running (starting at 1 and 4) and the travel time between nodes is 10 units. For now, I used the switch-cases to manage the event. However, if I need to expand the network, it might be very confusing to manage all the events with switch-cases technique.

Is there any solution to improve this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <queue>
#include <time.h>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


using namespace std;

double Clock, Travel_time_bw_block;


class Event
{


public:

enum EvtType {arrival_1, arrival_2, arrival_3, arrival_4, arrival_5, arrival_6};             

    Event(EvtType type = arrival_1, int bus_no = 0, double etime = 0.0):
_type(type),_bus_no(bus_no), _etime(etime) {}

    EvtType get_type() const
    {
        return _type;
    }
    double get_bus_no() const
    {
        return _bus_no;
    }
    double get_time() const
    {
        return _etime;
    }


protected:
    EvtType _type;
    int _bus_no;
    double _etime;
};



struct EventLess
{
    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.get_time() > rhs.get_time());
    }
};


priority_queue <Event, vector<Event>, EventLess> FutureEventList;


void Initialization()
{
    // initialize global variables
    Clock = 0.0;

    Travel_time_bw_block = 10.0;

    Event evt1(Event::arrival_1, 1, 0.0);
    Event evt2(Event::arrival_4, 2, 0.0);


    FutureEventList.push(evt1);
    FutureEventList.push(evt2);
}

int main(){

    int Simulation_Time = 200;
    Initialization();

    while(Clock < Simulation_Time){

        Event evt = FutureEventList.top();

        FutureEventList.pop();
        Clock = evt.get_time();

        switch(evt.get_type()){

            case Event::arrival_1:
            {
                cout << "bus " << evt.get_bus_no() << " arriving block 1 at: " << Clock << endl;
                Event enter_1 = Event(Event::arrival_2, evt.get_bus_no(), Clock + Travel_time_bw_block);
                FutureEventList.push(enter_1);
                break;
            }
            case Event::arrival_2:
            {
                cout << "bus " << evt.get_bus_no() << " arriving block 2 at: " << Clock << endl;
                Event enter_2 = Event(Event::arrival_3, evt.get_bus_no(), Clock + Travel_time_bw_block);
                FutureEventList.push(enter_2);
                break;
            }
            case Event::arrival_3:
            {
                cout << "bus " << evt.get_bus_no() << " arriving block 3 at: " << Clock << endl;
                Event enter_3 = Event(Event::arrival_4, evt.get_bus_no(), Clock + Travel_time_bw_block);
                FutureEventList.push(enter_3);
                break;
            }

            case Event::arrival_4:
            {
                cout << "bus " << evt.get_bus_no() << " arriving block 4 at: " << Clock << endl;
                Event enter_4 = Event(Event::arrival_5, evt.get_bus_no(), Clock + Travel_time_bw_block);
                FutureEventList.push(enter_4);
                break;
            }

            case Event::arrival_5:
            {
                cout << "bus " << evt.get_bus_no() << " arriving block 5 at: " << Clock << endl;
                Event enter_5 = Event(Event::arrival_6, evt.get_bus_no(), Clock + Travel_time_bw_block);
                FutureEventList.push(enter_5);
                break;
            }

            case Event::arrival_6:
            {
                cout << "bus " << evt.get_bus_no() << " arriving block 6 at: " << Clock << endl;
                Event enter_6 = Event(Event::arrival_1, evt.get_bus_no(), Clock + Travel_time_bw_block);
                FutureEventList.push(enter_6);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a long switch statement, replace it with a std::map. Simply you can reduce the size of your code. And your code will be more cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some observations that may help you improve your code.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Avoid the use of global variables

I see that `Clock` is used only within `main` (and `Initialization`) but it's declared as s global variable. It's generally better to explicitly pass variables your function will need or declare them within the appropriately smallest possible scope rather than using the vague implicit linkage of a global variable.  I'd recommend gathering these into a `BusSim` class instead.

### Use standard templates

The priority queue is currently declared like this:

```
priority_queue <Event, vector<Event>, EventLess> FutureEventList;
```

This is very strange for several reasons.  First `EventLess` is defined as a struct:

```
struct EventLess
{
    bool operator()(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.get_time() > rhs.get_time());
    }
};
```

Second, it has "less" in the name but uses ">" in the code.  It would be an understatement to describe this as counterintuitive!  Instead, I'd recommend creating a more typical operator function for the `Event` class:

```
bool operator>(const Event& lhs, const Event& rhs) 
{
    return lhs.get_time() > rhs.get_time();
}
```

Then declare the `priority_queue` like this:

```
std::priority_queue <Event, std::vector<Event>, std::greater<Event> > FutureEventList;
```

### Don't use `std::endl` if you don't really need it

The difference betweeen `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `'\n'` just emits a newline character, while `std::endl` actually flushes the stream.  This can be time-consuming in a program with a lot of I/O and is rarely actually needed.  It's best to *only* use `std::endl` when you have some good reason to flush the stream and it's not very often needed for simple programs such as this one.  Avoiding the habit of using `std::endl` when `'\n'` will do will pay dividends in the future as you write more complex programs with more I/O and where performance needs to be maximized.

### Use only required `#include`s

The code has a number of `#include`s that are not needed.  This clutters the code and makes it more difficult to read and understand.  Only include files that are actually needed.  In this code, I believe these are the only ones required:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
```

### Rethink your class design

Your comment about this design being confusing to manage is likely to be true the way it's currently written.  Instead, I think I'd design things a little differently.  In particular, I think I'd have a `Bus` object for each bus.  Each `Bus` would contain its own collection of `BusStop`s.  Then I would have the whole thing encapsulated in a `BusSim` class.  If that is done, the `main` could look like this:

```
int main(){
    BusSim sim(200);
    sim();
}
```